# How can I make Angular/HTML wait 1 second between cycles of ng-repeat?

Tags: html, angularjs

I have the following AngularJS/HTML code:

```
<tbody>
  <tr ng-repeat="currElement in myCtrl.elementList track by $index" >
    <td ng-class-odd="'element-tilt-left'" ng-class-even="'element-tilt-right'">
      <a ui-sref="myState({elementId: currElement.elementId)" ng-bind="currElement.name">
      </a>
    </td>
 </tr>
</tbody>
```

Instead of having a multi-row table, I would like a table with only a single row. The data in the `<td>` of that row should cycle among the elements of `myCtrl.elementList` with 1 second intervals. IE: the data displayed should change after every second. After the elements are exhausted, it should go back to the beginning of that list and repeat forever.

How can I do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using an `ng-repeat`, do something like this:

```
<tr>
    <td ng-class="{ 'element-tilt-left': myCtrl.currentIndex % 2 == 1, 'element-tilt-right': myCtrl.currentIndex % 2 == 0}">
        <a ui-sref="myState({elementId: myCtrl.currElement.elementId)" 
           ng-bind="myCtrl.currElement.name">
        </a>
    </td>
</tr>
```

And in your controller:

```
app.controller("myCtrl", function($scope, $interval) {

    var _self = this;

    _self.elementList = [
        // some array with your data
    ];

    _self.currentIndex = 0;

    _self.currentElem = _self.elementList[_self.currentIndex];

    var currentElementInterval = $interval(function() {
        _self.currentIndex++;
        if(_self.currentIndex >= _self.elementList.length) {
            _self.currentIndex = 0;
        }

        _self.currentElem = _self.elementList[_self.currentIndex];
    }, 1000);

    // remember to clear the interval to prevent memory leaks
    $scope.$on("destroy", function() {
        $interval.cancel(currentElementInterval);
        currentElementInterval = undefined;
    });
});
```